# How to make script stop deleting file from source folder

Tags: batch-file

I have this bat script that is supposed to copy the latest file from source to target folder. however, the script also deletes the file it seems in the source folder. what should i need to change to make it only copy, not necessarily delete?

```
@echo off
set source="C:\Users\plugins"
set target="C:\Users\target"

FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR %source%\*.jar* /A:-D /O:-D /B') DO COPY %source%\"%%I" %target% & echo %%I & GOTO :END
:END
TIMEOUT 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no command in your code which should delete files, so my suggestion is that you try to use recommended syntax with regards doublequotes.

```bat
@Echo off
Set "source=C:\PathTo\plugins"
Set "target=C:\PathTo\target"

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B /A-D /O-D /TW "%source%\*.jar" 2^>Nul'
) Do XCopy "%source%\%%A" "%target%\" /Y&GoTo End
:End
Timeout 4 >Nul
```